# Floating a container to the left moves it to the next line with a whitespace on the top

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put in the text container on the right parallel to my image using float:left (since the image is also float:left) for the container but it comes on the next line with a whitespace on the top of it.

Desired behaviour: The image should come on the left and the container should come on the right.

I've tried using display: inline for the container but that also doesn't work. Here is the js fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/b8weczkb/

Here is the code: HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>xxx</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="page">

 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" target="Myname">xxxx</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


 <div class="blogspace">

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2 align="center"><p class="text-info">abcd</p></h2>

  </div>

<div class="two-blocks">

  <div class="image">
    <img src="Imagebw.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" >
  </div>

  <div class="info">

  <div  class="information" >
    <h3>  <p class="Name">xxx</p></h3>
    <h5>  <p class="Category"><b>xxx</b></p></h5>
    <h6><p class="phone"><b>xx</b></p></h6>
    <h5><p class="number">xxx</p></h5>
    <h6><p class="email"><b>xx</b></p></h6>
    <h5><p class="myemail">xxx</p></h5>
    <h6><p class="Address"><b>xxxx</b></p></h6>
    <h5><p class="myaddress">xxxx</p></h5>
    <h6><p class="DOB"><b>xxxx</b></p></h6>
    <h5><p class="mydob"><h5>xxx</p></h5>
  </div>

</div>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.page{



}




@viewport{
  zoom:1.0;
  width:device-width;
}

nav.navbar{

  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 7.15em;
  border-style: solid;

}




div.jumbotron{
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right:15%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  opacity: 0.93;
  border-radius: 0!important;


}


.image{


height: 35.75em;
width: 28.6em;

border-style: solid;
border-color: red;

}

img{

width:100%;
height: 100%;

float:left;


}

.two-blocks{
  margin-left:15%;
  margin-right:15%;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  height: 38em;
}


div.information{

font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
color:darkslategrey;
background-image: url("black_dell.jpg");
opacity:0.97;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;

}

.info{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
   position: relative;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;

  height: 35.75em;
  width: 28.6em;

}

p.Name{
}

p.Category{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;

}

p.phone{
  margin-bottom:-10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
p.number{

 margin-bottom:30px;
 font-size:17px;
}

p.myemail{
  font-size:15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

p.email{
  font-size:17px;

  margin-bottom:-10px;
}



p.myaddress{
  font-size:15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

p.Address{
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-bottom:-10px;

}


p.mydob{
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-top:-10px;
}

p.DOB{
  font-size: 15px;
}


.navbar-nav >li a {

margin-top: 18px;
font-size: 20px;

}

a[target]{

font-size: 40px;
font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
}

.container-fluid > .navbar-header{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 45px !important;
}


nav.navbar{
  background-color:#362166;
  opacity: 0.93;
}

p.text-info{

 font-style: oblique;
 font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;


 overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
 border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
 white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
 margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
 letter-spacing: .10em; /* Adjust as needed */
 animation:
   typing 4.0s steps(40, end),
   blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;

}

.navbar-right
{

font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
}

body{

  background-image: url("chemistry.jpg");

}



/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange; }
}

h5:hover{

  font-size:20px !important;
}
```

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/b8weczkb/1/

Comment: @MichaelCoker, not exactly. Well you removed the whitespace but I also want the container that is down so that it be in parallel with the image on its right hand side and not below it (the image).

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a few issues with your CSS. I will mention a few of them.

1. You were setting a combined fixed width on both of the elements that were wider than the parent element.
2. You had set `float:left` on the `img` rather than the `.image` element.
3. On the `.info` element you were setting `display:inline`, `float:left` and `display:inline-block`. It just needed it to be `float:left`

https://jsfiddle.net/WizardCoder/b8weczkb/4/

Comment: thanks! Could you tell me some book/site/blog to learn responsive web design as well as all the elements of css? I already know w3schools and other websites but I want to have a firm knowledge of css.

Comment: HTML5: The Missing Manual, and CSS: The Missing Manual are pretty good, but you might want to search around to see what is best for you. This website is really good for interactive practical learning https://www.codecademy.com. You can register for free and a lot of the content is free. You could also look at https://www.khanacademy.org/ which is a similar concept. This free introduction course would probably be good for you. https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css. Also https://css-tricks.com/ is a really good blog.

Comment: @tWizardCoder, Thank you!